# Need to do multiple search at a time with starting character which is search in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am use https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple for autocomplete functionality in my site. Its work fine, Now I want to search record with first character that added to text box only.

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"><input type="text" id="multi"><script>$(document).ready(function() {var avail = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
];

$("#single").autocomplete({
    source:avail
});


 function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#multi" )
  // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
  .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  .autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        avail, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    },
    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
  });});</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap typeahead multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662824/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-multiple-values)

Comment: Take a look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12663455/1023562 with this demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/BwDmM/300/

Comment: thanks Ivan, this what I want.So now I want to do one additional think with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662824/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-multiple-values, like, to search record starting from first character, not all the record from where my searched character has been come, any idea?

Comment: Yes, explanation added in answer.

Answer (score 2):

As per comments:

To make the [typeahead.js multipel search demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/BwDmM/300) searching "starting from first character", change matching code line from this:

```
~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(tquery.toLowerCase())
```

to this:

```
item.toLowerCase().indexOf(tquery.toLowerCase()) == 0
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BwDmM/1100/

Additional note: more explanation about how the original matching code works (tilda bitwise operator) can be found here: http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/

Comment: sorry ivan, please refer my above question, I have just put my code over there.

Comment: Also I have find one answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177541/jquery-autocomplete-start-from-first-character but bit confuse, how to use that in my code. Its For your info

Comment: The question is about typeahead.js (*I am use the typeahead.js for autocomplete functionality in my site. Its work fine*), but the code you posted use only jQuery. What am I missing here?

Comment: I am extremely sorry, please forget typeahead.js and consider above code for multiple search.

Comment: Actually I could fail to use typeahead.js so I have use this one right now, https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple